# How to auto insert a code snippet when implementing an Interface like when implementing IDisposable

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to automatically insert a Code Snippet when an interface is implemented? If so, how do you do it? I am looking for something similar to when you implement IDispoable in VB.

e.g.

I have the following Interface

```
Public Interface ITransferable

    ReadOnly Property TransferParameters() As Object

End Interface
```

I also have a Code Snippet as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>Transfer Parameter Snippet</Title>
      <Author>RMC</Author>
      <Description>Transfer Parameter Snippet used when implementing the ITRansferable Interface</Description>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Code Language="VB" Kind="" Delimiter="$">
        <![CDATA[
          Private m_oTransferParameters As Object

          Public Class InputParameters
              'Add Input Parameter declaration/s here
          End Class

          Public Class OutputParameters
              'Add Output Parameter declaration/s here
          End Class

          Public ReadOnly Property TransferParameters() As Object Implements ITransferable.TranferParameters

              Get
                  Return m_oTransferParameters 
              End Get

          End Property
        ]]>
      </Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

So, what I want to happen, is when the ITransferable Interface is implemented, it injects the code in the code snippet into the class implementing the interface, such as

```
Public Class NewClass()
    Implements ITransferable

    Private m_oTransferParameters As Object

    Public Class InputParameters
        'Add Input Parameter declaration/s here
    End Class

    Public Class OutputParameters
        'Add Output Parameter declaration/s here
    End Class

    Public ReadOnly Property TransferParameters() As Object Implements ITransferable.TranferParameters

        Get
             Return m_oTransferParameters 
         End Get

    End Property

End Class
```

This will be used by web forms when transfering parameters from one page to the next using Server.Transfer

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio 2008 Team System - Dev Edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after a lot of digging around on the net, and not coming up with much, I have ended up using a custom item template to accomplish what i needed to do as I want all web forms to inherit from the ITransferable Interface, now when a developer wants to create a new web form, they select my custom one from the 'Add New Item' popup, this then creates a web page with all the code in that I required. I hope this is of some use to someone.